# Limiting Twitter API Usage to One Monthly Cap for Retrieving Replies to a Tweet

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2

I am working on a project where I need to retrieve user IDs of those who replied to a specific tweet using the Twitter API. However, I want to ensure that I only use one monthly API cap for this task. It seems that the Search endpoint usage is tied to the number of users it returns. How can I achieve this?

I am currently using the Twitter API and the Search endpoint to retrieve user IDs of those who replied to a specific tweet.